# How do I get an interaction between 2 buttons (Angular)?

Tags: html, angular

I have two buttons that when activated
show the content of "shouldTrianglePropertyBeShown" or "shouldShapeBeShown".  When I click a button, the color of the respective button also changes. Unfortunately, it is currently so that if one button is activated and I also activate the other button that both contents are displayed to me. Of course I would prefer if one is activated then the other should be deactivated.

I have tried several things but unfortunately I have not managed to create an interaction between the two buttons.

Does anyone have a tip for me how to disable another button and its content ?

Here is my code:

MY PAGE.TS

```
selectTriangleProperty(shownPropertiesNumber: number) {
    this.arePropertiesOfTriangleVisible[shownPropertiesNumber] = !this.arePropertiesOfTriangleVisible[shownPropertiesNumber];
    this.getStatusOfButtonDetailsActivation(shownPropertiesNumber);

  }
  shouldTrianglePropertyBeShown(shownPropertiesNumber: number) {
    this.getStatusOfButtonDetailsActivation(shownPropertiesNumber);
    return this.arePropertiesOfTriangleVisible[shownPropertiesNumber];
  }
  selectShapeInformation(shownShapeNumber: number) {
    this.areShapeInformationVisible[shownShapeNumber] = !this.areShapeInformationVisible[shownShapeNumber];
    this.getStatusOfButtonShapeActivation(shownShapeNumber);

  }
  shouldShapeBeShown(shownShapeNumber: number) {
    this.getStatusOfButtonShapeActivation(shownShapeNumber);
    return this.areShapeInformationVisible[shownShapeNumber];
  }
  
  
  getStatusOfButtonDetailsActivation(shownPropertiesNumber: number)
  {
    const propertyButtonActivated = document.getElementById('structure-properties-button');
    const informationButtonActivated = document.getElementById('shape-information-button');
    if(this.arePropertiesOfTriangleVisible[shownPropertiesNumber])
    {
    propertyButtonActivated.style.backgroundColor = '#9AD2C9';
  }
    else if(!this.arePropertiesOfTriangleVisible[shownPropertiesNumber])
    {
      propertyButtonActivated.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
    }
  }
  getStatusOfButtonShapeActivation(shownShapeNumber: number)
  {
    const informationButtonActivated = document.getElementById('shape-information-button');
    if(this.areShapeInformationVisible[shownShapeNumber])
    {
      informationButtonActivated.style.backgroundColor = '#9AD2C9';}
    else if(!this.areShapeInformationVisible[shownShapeNumber])
    {
      informationButtonActivated.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
    }
  }
```

MY HTML

```
<ion-buttons>
    <ion-button id="triangle-properties-button" class="table-button-green"
       (click)="selectTriangleProperty(j)">
        Details
    </ion-button>
</ion-buttons>
<ion-buttons>  
  <ion-button id="shape-information-button" class="table-button-white" (click)="selectBridgeInformation(j)">
    Brückeninformationen
  </ion-button>
</ion-buttons>

<ion-row *ngIf="shouldTrianglePropertyBeShown(j)" size="12" class="content-subrow" id="triangle-properties" >
          <ion-col size="4" *ngFor="let property of triangle.triangleProperties" style="margin-top: 8px; background-color:#f9efef; ">
           <div class="detailView__label">{{property.propertyName}}</div> 
           <div class="detailView__text"> {{property.propertyValue}}</div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row *ngIf="shouldShapeBeShown(j)" size="12" class="content-subrow" id="triangle-properties" >
          
        <ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

HTML:

```
<ion-buttons>
    <ion-button 
       [disabled]="activateShape"
       id="triangle-properties-button" 
       class="table-button-green"       
       (click)="selectTriangleProperty(j); activateShape=!activateShape;activateTriangle= false;">
       Details
    </ion-button>
</ion-buttons>

<ion-buttons>  
  <ion-button 
       [disabled]="activateTriangle"
       id="shape-information-button" 
       class="table-button-white"
       (click)="selectBridgeInformation(j); activateTriangle=!activateTriangle; activateShape=false;">
       Brückeninformationen
  </ion-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

TS (as attributes of your Class):

```
activateShape = false;
activateTriangle = false;
```

NOTE: If that works fine, you can move all the logic of the "clicks" to functions in the ts.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't quite work. We can still display both contents. And if I click on the first button then the content remains and the button remains disabled.

Comment: Try use `(click)="selectTriangleProperty(j); activateShape=!activateShape; activateTriangle= false;"` on the first button and `(click)="selectBridgeInformation(j); activateTriangle=!activateTriangle; activateShape=false;"` on the second button.

Comment: @DonJuwe I like your idea, that was basically what I was trying to achieve, I I foolishly forgot to change the other button. I will edit in my answer in that way, thank you!